# Does eigenvalue theory remain in numerical applications?

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If I have a symmetric matrix $A \in \mathbb{Q}^{n \times n}$ in matlab, then in theory it is guaranteed that $A$ has a  orthogonal basis of eigenvectors and real eigenvalues. Does this remain in numercial applications or does it fail because of the way matlab (or any other software) computes eigenvectors? Same question for the product of $A B$ where $A$ is symmetric, positive definite and $B$ is just symmetric, then in theorey it is guaranteed that $A B$ has a basis of eigenvectors and real eigenvalues, does it remain in numerical applications?

To clear things up: I am not talking about an approximation of a symmetric matrix but actually a symmetric matrix that is stored in computer memory (this is why I assumed $A \in \mathbb{Q}^{n \times n}$ instead of $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$).

Comment: Are you asking whether machine precision approximation of eigenvectors is an orthogonal basis?

Comment: A program like matlab is going to use numerical methods to compute the eigenvectors and eigenvalues, so the eigenvectors will be (comprised of components which are) floating point numbers which are approximately equal to true eigenvectors and are approximately orthogonal.  If you wanted to take advantage of the fact that you know the entries of the matrix exactly, you could use an algebra package like gp or magma, which would compute the eigenvectors and eigenvalues exactly as elements of a number field.  Does this answer your question, or is there more to it?

Comment: This answers the part about eigenvectors. But does it mean also that my eigenvalues can become complex?